# Paginate() function is returning all the data in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
$products = $this->productRepository->paginate(1);
```

I want to get only one item at a time but the paginate() function related to pagination are not working. My laravel version is 5.7.6. when i use dd($products) it returns:

```
Collection {#468 
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Product {#469}
    1 => Product {#470}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the collection directly which does not paginate.
Try `$products = $this->productRepository()->paginate(1);` using `productRepository()` gives you the query builder instead, which you can then paginate